# CodeNameOne Gradient Render In IOS

Tags: gradient, codenameone

In codenameone, i use vertical gradient for a button.

When i build IOS version, and install it, at the startup it's ok, but after 1 second, gradient removed and the first color fill.

In android it's ok.

IOS 7.1.2 (11D257)

Comment: in this post, it reported before and has been fixed.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/1iXiAm9daCs

but it does't work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you avoid gradient fills. They are VERY slow and take up a lot of RAM!

Use image backgrounds or 9-patch image borders which are both faster and more memory efficient. This is covered in the performance how do I: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---improve-application-performance-or-track-down-performance-issues.html